# How to encode periods for a URL in a JScript Parameter

Tags: javascript, parsing, url, escaping, bbcode

I'm coding a live JavaScript parser for a forum website that I'm designing but I've encountered a seemingly simple hiccup that I just can't fix.

I've got the live JavaScript parser to bold letters, change colors, embed YouTube videos, and even nest quotes! But for some reason, it just doesn't want to work with URL's (I've deduced that this is because of the periods.)

So, the text that's being parsed looks like typical bbcode...
For example:

```
 [b]this text will be bold[/b]

 [youtube]youtube link[/youtube]

 [quote=Jake said:]hello world![/quote]
```

All of these work to produce the desired result. But this:

```
 [url=www.example.com]Link Name[/url]
```

Doesn't work! If I replace link name with the actual link it works, but when I include the link as a parameter so that it can be renamed (it works for the quotes) it doesn't work because of the periods in the link. So, my question is, how can I escape these periods whenever one types a URL.

Here's my parsing code for the URL.

```
   'url': {
    openTag: function(params,content) {

        var name = content;
        var uri = params;
        var myUrl = encodeURIComponent(uri);

        return '<a href=' + myUrl + '>'+ name +'</a>';
    },
    closeTag: function(params,content) {
        return '';
    },
content: function(params,content) {
    return '';
}
},
```

If I swap the myUrl and Name variables in the return it works fine, but I am unable to edit the URL (say make the URL a different color) because the actual display part (Name) becomes the parameter. So, how can I get myUrl to work while still being the parameter?

Here's the code for the quote which is very similar and does work. (It will not work, however, if the parameter includes a period, just like with the URL).

```
'quoter': {
openTag: function(params,content) {

    var myUrl = content;
    var name = params;
    return '<div><div class="quotetitle">'+ name +' said:</div><div class="quote">' + myUrl + '</div></div>';
},
closeTag: function(params,content) {
    return '';
},
content: function(params,content) {
return '';
}
},
```

Comment: Why do you need to escape the periods, periods are characters in urls, in your parsing code for url, you would just get myUrl = 'www.example.com', isn't that what you want?

Comment: @teaflavored hi tea flavored!  It is what I want, for some reason it wont parse when there's periods.   For example [url=hello]text[/url] sucesfully results in "text" with a link to url.  But this [url=www.hello.com]text[/url] results in [url=www.hello.com]text[/url] unparsed.

Comment: hmm I think you should provide more information as to how you're converting the whole string '[url=hello]text[/url]' from beginning to end

Comment: @JakeStief if you can offload BBCode processing to the backend then my Shortcode library may come in handy: https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode